# How did people distinguish slaves from free people in Ancient Rome?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, slavery

I've tried to find some information about it, but failed. Let's say there is an educated slave living in a relatively rich household of Rome. What would prevent him from fleeing, going to some smaller town of some province to live there as a free man? It's not like they had lists of all free citizens, neither did they have proper identification documents, such as a modern-day passport, which would identify them. And not every single slave wore a collar (which still can be broken).

Comment: Welcome and +1.

Comment: IIRC, interestingly there were proposals to dress slaves differently; but those were shot down out of fears that the slaves would realise how numerous they were.

Comment: I think there was an “état-civil” (civil register).

Comment: @Semaphore — Very interesting. Is this linked to the revolt of the slaves guided by Spartacus ?

Comment: If I recall correctly there were fairly dramatic punishments for attempting this. Most people are law abiding; there are plenty of crimes that we are smart enough to get away with, but we choose to obey the law even when it is inconvenient.  Finally, one couldn't just "move into a town"; purchasing property was only available to a wealthy class who all knew one another's relatives.  If the slave had a profession and tried to practice the profession in the new town, the incumbents would object.

Comment: I just wonder about one more thing. Consider that someone new moves to a town/village, noone knows if he's a slave or free man... Would it matter anyway? If you capture some stranger who has no acquanintanances, you could sell him as a slave?

Comment: I imagine the penalty for trying to unlawfully enslave a free person would be even more severe than a slave running. Ditto for owning one. The free man's family finds you, expect bloodshed.

Comment: How would you move to a new village/town?  You'd need to arrive with enough money to purchase property, or with an introduction to someone who lives there. Until you have a social introduction to the town, you are a stranger, and nobody will deal with a stranger. (there is a reason that pre-modern societies treat hospitality as a virtue; it wasn't common or normal).  Everyone in Rome was part of a social network - family, gens, tribe, neighborhood, etc.  The concept of "individual" didn't exist as we know it today.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well,  I suppose  it's a matter of means plus motivation.  If you're educated - read/speak Greek and Latin etc - then you'd be valuable,  and only the psychopathic master would mistreat a valuable peice of property. And you'd need money to get away - some slaves were relatively wealthy,  but stealing from your master would be dangerous,  the penalties could be horrendous.  Then,  if you got to this new town, how would you live? If you were educated,  even if  a slave,  you'd consider manual work beneath you - and,  of course,  slavery has the effect of reducing the value of free labour, why pay someone when you can own them? He (it would be far more difficult for a woman) could become a schoolmaster,  but that was no sinecure in the Roman world, living in a cramped tenement, always looking over your shoulder in case you were discovered. You're right,  very few slaves actually wore collars, although badges have been found with inscriptions like "1belong to M Julius Horrendus,  if you find me,  send me back."  - which seems a bit daft,  as presumably, if they were just badges, they could be removed! And - I'm no expert,  but suspect there was a cultural aspect here - if you were a slave, then it was because the gods had made you one.

Interestingly, the Senate grappled with this problem,  there was a move - sorry, can't give a date - to decree that all slaves had to wear distinctive dress. It was abandoned out of fear that,  if the slaves realised how numerous they were,  they'd rise in rebellion.

So, for the educated slave,  without a psychopath for a master,  engaged in teaching the children or dealing with his master's business affairs, it was probably better to wait and hope he would be able to buy or be given his freedom, rather than risk being caught,  flogged or worse, and sent to the salt mines!

As I said before,  there could be genuine affection between masters and slaves - much  the way 19th century servants in the UK felt about "Miss Alice"  or "Master George".  During the US civil War, a slave boy was sent to join the Confederate Army with the young master. His master was killed,  the slave buried him,  wrote a letter to his parents - then high-tailed it to the Unionists to fight for freedom!

If you haven't, you might like to read Plautus' play,  ["The Prisoners"](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0096%3Aact%3Dintro), which gives a very interesting insight into slave/master relationships.

Comment: So, it's not like they couldn't get away, it's more about if they wanted to escape, which leads to a few conclusions. 1. A life of a slave wasn't that bad. 2. There were slaves who escaped slavery. It's just a matter of "will and courage". And thanks for the advice on The Prisoners, didn't have a chance to read it yet.

Comment: The lives of some slaves were terrible, but they were precisely the ones who probably couldn't escape or if they did would have to resort to brigandage to survive. As I read somewhere - sorry, can't the remember where - most slaves didn't object to  slavery per se, just that they were slaves!

Comment: It's more about educated slaves for me, because they could be quite indistinguishable from patrician if they wanted.

Comment: Hmm... doubt that. I'm prepared to be corrected, but the patricians were a fairly small group of inter-married clans, you'ld soon be found out! And there was a clear distinction between  citizens, who were entitled to wear the toga, and the rest, who weren't. Interestingly, a freedman automatically became a Roman citizen and a member of his master's "family" - when Tiro,  M Tulius Cicero's slave, was freed, he became M Tulius Tiro - a Roman citizen.

Comment: Yes, of course he would be found out rather soon. It's like claiming to be the Queen :) But he would be able to bahave like one, talk like one and wear the same dresses. In a way indistinguishable for those unaware he's an impostor.

Comment: @TheHonRose: I suspect the badges were for slaves who couldn't speak Latin, so they could show it to someone if they got lost.

Comment: Some types of slavery were more akin to a long term contract - the Greek slave educators, say - who were trading the work for the citizenship that being a freed Roman slave gave you.

Comment: @Oldcat can you please reference that?  I'm no Classicist, but I've never heard of Roman slavery being term-limited? Thanks.

Comment: See Wiki on "Education in Ancient Rome", provides an instance. If not term-limited, there must have been some kind of understanding for Greeks to become slave-educators. It isn't like they were being captured in battle.

Comment: If you read the history of Education in Rome, almost all the starters of schools were freedmen. Again, this means they were slaves, that got freed at some point. If not a fixed rule, it was certainly a common habit.

Comment: @TheHonRose at least there were laws to free slaves at old age and unable to work.

Comment: @Anix - sorry, can't the reference this, it's late and I'm too tired/lazy to look it up, but some elderly slaves were freed to save their masters the cost of their upkeep! And readers - many if not most rich Romans had slaves to read to them - often went blind, reading by lamp-light. Will try to evidence this comment, but not tonight!

Comment: @Oldcat I see no reference to such instance in the Wikipedia article. And, first, one didn't have to be captured in battle to become a slave - piracy was rife until near the end of the Republic. Secondly, if you trade your freedom for a stated number of years for the advantage of citizenship, then that is **not** chattel slavery as generally understood, more a form of indentured servitude. The *point* of chattel slavery is that it is **involuntary** on the part of the slave. And there were no doubt educated slaves in the Hellenistic world who would fetch a better price in Rome!

Comment: The Romans called it slavery.  Slave tutors were slaves.  You are just repeating what I said, but saying one isn't slavery.  But to the Romans, both were slavery.  The point of having a slave tutor was that he couldn't quit being a tutor until you freed him.

Comment: @Oldcat Well, the OP is wondering why an educated slave didn't just run away. You are suggesting it was a kind of "voluntary servitude" (there's an oxymoron!), entered into for the benefit of citizenship - in which case he'd have no incentive to r! And he probably didn't have to, manumission rates were extraordinarily high, particularly for skilled slaves.

Comment: See Peter Temin The Labor Market of the Early Roman Empire for the economy advantages of masters educating their slaves. There are many kinds of unfree labour - serf, indentured servant, etc, but I have seen no suggestion anywhere that Rome practised anything other than **chattel** slavery, in which the slave was as much the master's property, and, at least up to the Empire, had as few rights, as his table or chair!

Comment: An educated slave that runs is subject to the full force of punishment that law and custom allowed.  Presumably, an educated Greek entering slavery to teach a rich man's kids would have reasonable assurances that he would be given his freedom and dealt with well, and not sold to the salt mines, or nobody would enter into the deal.  And you are right about legal rights, but that isn't the total picture.  Look at women - legally the rights of women were severely restricted, but in fact a wife and daughter of major families had considerable influence not defined in any law.

Comment: @Oldcat  Sorry, you just claim that educated Greeks entered slavery "voluntarily" for the benefits of citizenship/patronage, with a "gentleman's agreement" as to terms. Until you offer some evidence, we're just going "Yes they did! " No they didn't!" which is pointless.

Comment: It is hard to credit that the Roman slave education system was based on pirate raids on Greek towns, which is the only alternative you have given.  The last war against Greece was in 130 BC, so battle is out as a source of these slaves.

Comment: You are extrapolating a conclusion from no evidence. Offer *some* evidence and we can discuss it.

Comment: Another reason to not have government mandates for mode of dress for slaves (or anyone) was that it was considered not to be the government's business to intrude in citizens' private affairs in such ways. If they'd tried there might well have been a revolt from not just slaves but slave owners!

Comment: @TheHonRose it was quite possible for someone to enter into a contract where they'd become an unpaid manservent (effectively a slave in all but name) for a specified period in order to gain the sponsorship of the other contract party to gain for example citizenship. Other slaves were criminals, convicted to a specific period of slavery as punishment and retribution for their crimes.

Comment: "Slaves numbering in the tens of thousands were condemned to work in the mines or quarries, where conditions were notoriously brutal.[57] Damnati in metallum ("those condemned to the mine") were convicts who lost their freedom as citizens (libertas), forfeited their property (bona) to the state, and became servi poenae, slaves as a legal penalty. Their status under the law was different from that of other slaves; they could not buy their freedom, be sold, or be set free."   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_ancient_Rome

Comment: Are there any sources for any of this?

Comment: @spacetyper Sources for which parts of it?

Answer (score 26):

Although, as you say, a rich slave might be able to engineer an escape, most slaves were not rich and not educated.

Slaves could generally be immediately recognized by their dress. Although there were no laws mandating dress for a slave, they tended to wear clothing which set them apart. For example, no slave could wear the toga, so if a man is wearing a toga, you know right off the bat it is a citizen. Also, the tunics worn by freemen tended to be a lot nicer and more expensive than the plain tunics worn by slaves. Likewise for their footwear, which was expensive. Slaves often went barefoot. In general, if you saw a guy with no shoes wearing a plain tunic, it was high probability he was a slave. Freeman also wore hats, called a pileus, which slaves generally were not supposed to do (see below for more about this). Also, there was an ethnic component, since slaves were foreigners, not Latins.

Slaves also had a different, much cruder, speech than the upper classes, which is often parodied in Roman plays. The educated in Rome studied diction and speech extensively in school and spoke in a way completely different than the slaves. If you read Plautus' plays, for example, you can learn how he parodies the speech of slaves. Also, note that in plays the free always wear togas and the slaves always wear tunics so the audience knows which is which.

If a slave was freed, he shaved his head to be completely bald, and then wore a *plain* (uncolored) pileus, which was a felt cap. Some citizens wore this cap, but always colored or decorated. A man with a bald head and plain pileus was a manumitted slave.

As for runaways, *fugitivi*, this was always a small problem, but it was hard.  In those days travel was expensive so people tended to stay in one place and strangers stood out. Where would you get the money? Usually you needed to have permission to become a citizen of a town, so if you just ran to some random town and applied for citizenship, the authorities would want to know who you were. People abroad on highways were regularly stopped and either had to have a passport or a really good story. Remember the highways were the property of the state in those days and were controlled by the military. Random people were not allowed to just waltz along highways the way they do now. There were severe penalties for people who hid or took in fugitivi as their own, so though it did occur, it was an illegal and risky move. You stood a good chance of getting ratted out by your neighbor or an enemy if you tried hiding a fugitive.

Finally, there were the dreaded *fugitivarii*, the slave hunters. These guys were professional fugitive locators and they were very good at their job. They had spies everywhere. Not only could they track a particular slave down, but they would grab you if you just looked like a fugitivus. Then they would torture you to reveal your owner. If you gave a fake name, they would just torture you again until you fessed up your real owner. Then they would take you to him and demand a fee from him for returning you.

Comment: Very good answer! I am a bit puzzled by two points: (a) How do you know about the toga/tunic distinction in Plautus? Is it in stage directions or somehow worked into the main text of the plays or what? (b) The statement that the highways were *owned* by the state does not seem right to me. What is the basis for it? Thanks!

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Both of these questions are kind of tangential to the main issue. If you read a book on Roman drama, it will explain the conventions and stereotypes used. The main highways built by the Romans were for the use of the military. Any use by a civilian was purely at the pleasure of the military authorities. In fact, in England, even after the Romans were gone their roads were treated as special military roads by the Saxons. The via militaria are also known as "consular roads" because in the days of the republic they were sponsored by consuls.

Comment: All along the consular roads were police stations manned by soldiers. These men had the power to summarily execute anybody on the road. They rigidly enforced rules about passports and who was allowed to go forth on the road.

Comment: What about passports? Somehow I thought that these didn't exist back then.

Comment: @Sappy They did. A slave abroad on a highway would probably at a minimum have to have a codicillus from his master and a official diploma authorizing him to be on the road for a particular purpose.

Comment: Yes,  I seem to remember one commentator - possibly a doctor - complaining bitterly about rich young men spending  all ther money on gambling and prostitutes,  whilst their slaves shivered in the cold without cloaks!

Comment: But a free man would not need a passport, would he?

Comment: @Tyler Durden What are your sources? Non-citizens wouldn't have any passport in first place. And I seriously doubt that plebs would have any on themselves at every time. Sure they may have civitatem, but it may be useless. Mostly because such document wouldn't prove anything. You can steal or forge one. The only method to actually prove yourself as a citizen, to make an inquiry, which would take a lot of time. Furthermore if a man claims to be from Rome, I'm not sure such an inquire would bring anything, if the person claims to be a person who really exists.

Comment: @TylerDurden I also seem to remember reading that if a slave escaped, his master would have him "proclaimed" in the foru /market place,  with description and details of the reward he was offering?

Comment: Very interesting article on Roman slavery :-     http://www.ancient.eu/article/629/

Comment: This is not the right forum (no pun intended) to get into the details of Roman passage laws and practices. These practices varied significantly over the hundreds of years of the republic and the empire. As a rule everybody, slave or free, on a military or consular road had to have a good reason to be there and would usually have a diploma to that effect, unless they were a soldier traveling with their unit. The details of this are not important. The important thing is that a lone slave without a letter or diploma would find it difficult to travel safely and not be arrested on a highway.

Comment: @Sappy Ancient passports were not like modern ones. They were usually one-time tokens, tablets or documents that authorized a single passage at a specific time or date. For example, if a slave was carrying, say letters, from Rome to Pompeii, before he left Rome he would get a diploma authorizing him to travel on the highway there, and the story would be same for most people, including soldiers who would carry their orders. You could always try to talk or bribe your way past the checkpoints, but remember that the soldiers were authorized by decree to kill anyone found illegally on the highway.

Comment: @Tyler Durden Thanks for the explanation, cleared some points to me. Although I'll read some literature about it. It seems to be quite interesting.

Comment: Pace Tyler Dundee, found this in an (admittedly old) book:-

"A Greek in Rome in the middle of the second century AD was struck by the lack of outward distinction between slaves and free me.  For instance,  their clothes were the same; ... But Juvenal was obviously right to remark that a rich man's slave was better of than a destitute citizen. "

And again:-

"...  in view of Rome's traditional policy of freeing many slaves, the knights, too, we're very often descended from freedmen. So were numerous members of the Senate."
(The World of Rome by Michael Grant  London 1960)

Comment: @TheHonRose As I said above, although it is technically true their clothes were the same, you could usually tell the difference by one means or another. Later in the empire, there were so many freed slaves it became harder and harder to tell.

Comment: Is it documented, that those fugitivarii sometimes captured and enslaved a free man, or there were some protections against it?

Comment: This answer extensively contradicts what is said elsewhere on the page. It is claimed elsewhere that the senate backed down from passing a law requiring slaves to dress differently because then the slaves would recognise that they were numerous enough to take over. But you're claiming that they already dressed distinctively differently so why would that law be needed? And do the conventions of stage drama necessarily correspond to real life? For example, today we see a lot of musicals in the theatre but people don't generally break into song like that. (Well, at least I don't.)

Comment: @Tyler Durden do you have any link that person on road without good excuse will be executed? And if so, would it be possible to sneak to freedom off road? Other than that very interesting and makes sense.

Comment: As an interesting datapoint about master-slave relations, Jefferson has his slave, Sally Hemings, in France. She could just walk away, because slavery was not recognized in France. She did not, and returned to slavery in USA, because Jefferson promised her to free all her children. So relations with other slaves might be also part of the picture.

Comment: @PeterMasiar What does this have to do with my answer?

Comment: Slave might chose not to escape master for certain benefits for other slaves, which would be lost if s/he escaped. But I was more interested about why people on road can be executed. I +1 your answer btw.

Comment: @PeterMasiar I did not want to get into the personal motivations for being a slave, since the premise of the OP is that the slave wants to escape. The given "reason" for having police stop people is to stop "crime" like banditry or smuggling. Count yourself lucky to live in a country where you don't get stopped by soldiers every 5 miles.

Comment: @TylerDurden "Slaves also had a different, much cruder, speech than the upper classes, which is often parodied in Roman plays."  But the OP is talking about educated slaves - they were probably the ones who taught patrician youths to speak/write Greek/Latin in the first place! In one of Cicero's letters to Tiro, the latter has obviously critiqued his master's /patron's syntax, and Cicero's reaction is "Oh, do you think so? Yes, perhaps you're right."

Comment: not just slaves would be barefoot and wear simple clothes. Many people couldn't afford anything else, and many who could potentially afford footwear would choose not to wear it because of the price (and lack of comfort) unless there was a specific need.